# How to disable an iframe in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can an iframe be disabled using Javascript, such that the user is unable to interact with the iframe's contents (i.e. scrolling, selecting, dragging, etc)? For example, a Google map in an iframe can normally be dragged and zoomed. How would these actions be prevented?

Comment: What do you mean disable? Not show it?

Comment: @Lea: disabled functionality as in other control like input etc. In simple words, blurred out and it should not editable.

Comment: How can we get this question reopened?  I have an answer, but I can't provide it with the question closed.

Answer (score 14):

If you're wanting to disable mouse interaction, this should work.

Put a DIV over the top of your iframe, like so (replace top, left, width and height values with your own):

```
<div id="blank" style="display:none; position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:600px; height:400px;">
```

and when you want to disable the iframe, do this in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("blank").style.display="block";
```

Comment: Thank's not disabling. That's hiding mate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use the `disabled` property like input elements, but you could disable mouse interaction by placing an element over the `iframe`, though this doesn't stop a user from tabbing to it.

Probably the best bet is to set the `src` attribute to blank, but this will make the `iframe` blank, not blurred.

Comment: setting the src to blank would hide the content of the iframe. That's not what the asker wants. I do like your idea of placing another element over it, since I checked, and the disabled attribute doesn't work on an iframe.

Comment: @Lea Well that meets the definition of being *disabled* doesn't it? BTW, the comment they left was after I answered.