# How can i disable the iframe？

Tags: javascript, html

My website have a iframe element. And this iframe element is visible, But it can't be operated. I mean all html elements in the iframe can't be clicked and can't be inputted content and so on. So What should i do?

Comment: put another div in front of the iframe

Comment: What's the role of that iframe? Use an image then!

Comment: Do you want it to be unclickable?  Or is this an error?

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano Such as '<div><iframe>..<iframe></div>'? But it don't worked

Comment: @Vohuman This iframe is a facebook widget. But i want to this iframe only can visible

Comment: @pianoman99 No only unclickable. Any event and action can't be fire..

Comment: You may have other HTML elements that are overlaying the iframe and therefore not allowing the click or input actions. Maybe you can create a self contained example of your problem in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Try using `pointer-events: none` property. I haven't tried it on an `iframe` though.

Comment: @Rima Thanks! Overlaying the iframe is a good solution.

Comment: @Vohuman I tried it. It can work. That's great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to disable mouse interaction, this should work.

Put a DIV over the top of your iframe, like so (replace top, left, width and height values with your own):

```
<div id="blank" style="display:none; position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:600px; height:400px;">
```

and when you want to disable the iframe, do this in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("blank").style.display="block";
```

### I am not taking credit for this answer.  This answer was by @Simon M on a duplicate question @ [How to disable an iframe in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482646/how-to-disable-an-iframe-in-javascript)